# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple convert list to text

Tags: django, django-views

I have a checkboxselectmultiple in my forms in my view im trying to concatenate each item in the list and save it as one big string.

this is how i have it. doesn't seem to work what do i do?

```
conditions = form.conditions
for conditions in conditions:
    con = con + conditions
table.conditions = table.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
one_big_string = ' '.join(request.POST.getlist('myselectmultiple'))
mymodelinstance.field = one_big_string 
mymodelinstance.save()
```

I can guess at a few problems:

1. You assign something to `table.conditions` but never save it.
2. `MyModelInstance.save()` doesn't return anything by default, so you're most likely assigning `None` to `table.conditions`

Hope that helps - if you clarify your question at all I will respond in the morning.